# Do holes affect the type of function (even, odd or neither)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, rational-functions, even-and-odd-functions

We can know whether a function is even or odd by substituting using F(-x) but what if the function has a single hole like this

f(x) = $\frac{x(x-2)}{x-2}$

is such a function considered odd or neither? since substitution in the original function will confirm that it is neither while substitution after simplification will confirm that it is odd

Comment: Why is $\dfrac {x (x - 2)} {x - 2}$ not odd? Surely $\dfrac {x - 2} {x - 2}$ is always $1$ except where $x = 2$, unless you disallow the term for odd-except-for-a-hole.

Comment: Substituting with f(-x) it will be $\frac{-x(-x-2)}{-x-2}$ which is clearly not equal to -f(x)

Comment: The hole at the 2 is not reflected across the origin if you got what I mean @PrimeMover

Comment: Replace the word "hole" by "pole".

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to replace "hole" by "singularity" as a pole is a special kind of singularity?  (In our case it's a removable one.)

Comment: @AhmedMoustafa Apart from that point at $2$, I really think $-f(x)$ *is* equal to $f(-x)$. I can't understand what you're saying.

Answer (score 5):

It depends upon *how* you defined odd function and even function. Let $D\subset\Bbb R$.

- If you say that a function $f\colon D\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ is odd if $x\in D\implies-x\in D$ and $f(-x)=-f(x)$ (this would be my definition), then $f$ is not odd (since $-2$ belongs to its domain, but $2$ doesn't).
- If you say that a function $f\colon D\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ is odd if, whenever both $x$ and $-x$ belong to $D$, then $f(-x)=-f(x)$, then your function *is* odd.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Thank you.